# After clicking the button the globalCompositeOperation not working...how can i do that to get the expected answer as the second canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Compositing Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>

  <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas> <br>

  <button onclick="composite()">Composite</button> <br>

  <p>Result Should be : </p>
  
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    // 1st Canvas

    let canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx1.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

    // globalCompositeOperation = "source-over|source-atop|source-in|source-out|destination-over|destination-atop|destination-in|destination-out|lighter|copy|xor"
    function composite() {
      ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    };

    ctx1.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx1.arc(110, 110, 80, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx1.fill();

    // 2nd Canvas

    let canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

    ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

    ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx2.arc(110, 110, 80, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

  </script>
  <br/>
</body>
</html>

After clicking the button, the globalCompositeOperation is not working...how can i do that for the expected answer?
the expected answer is in the second Canvas or second image...
why it is not working...?
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me cite the following paragraph out of [Compositing and clipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing) over at developer.mozilla.org:

> globalCompositeOperation = type
> This sets the type of compositing operation to apply when drawing new shapes, where type is a string identifying which of the twelve
> compositing operations to use.

The key here is: '...when drawing **new** shapes...'

So changing the composite operation for your canvas as the last command in the drawing chain doesn't affect shapes drawn priorly.